# Does page-fault effect performance much, by forking child process?

Tags: linux, fork, copy-on-write, page-fault

I have a busy process which occupies 30% CPU and 1G memory usage, at Linux.
The process makes a snapshot every hour, by calling `fork()` to create a child process which writes all data to a file. It takes about 1second.

I found that the father process's CPU usage becomes about 60% during the snapshot.

I guess the reason may be: forking a child makes most memory as Copy-on-write, and child process just reads memory so it does not trigger page-fault to copy pages, while the father process triggers many page-fault which results to a higher CPU usage.

Am I right? Can page-fault effects performance so much?

Thanks
Wu

== add stats ==

I count the page-fault by `ps -o min_flt`, and there are ~7k page-faults per second. Is it effects performance much?

Comment: Answer No (not in the simple way you describe). Suggest reading [Understanding page faults and memory swap-in/outs: when should you worry?](https://scoutapm.com/blog/understanding-page-faults-and-memory-swap-in-outs-when-should-you-worry)

Comment: Actually yes. Rendering the existing pages copy-on-write as well as forking the page table *should* be as cheap as it gets, and page-faults afterwards resolve at a rate of 5-15GB/s. Theoretically. There is a worst-case-scenario you are likely hitting here: Contention on the parent process' page table. Triggering a page fault while the page table is locked for other updates send you straight into a spinlock within the page fault interrupt. Gets worse with more threads contending for memory writes and therefor page faults, up to entirely starving the single working thread of memory bandwidth.

Comment: @Ext3h Both the father and child processes have only 1 thread. And the child just dump data so do not write the shared page. So I think there should be no contention.

Comment: If no thread is running during the fork, then it should not take a second to fork just 1GB of memory. And neither should you get page-faults during the fork in any signficant number. 7k pagefaults with 4k-pages only correspond to 28MB of memory, which is more than plausible (even cloning the page-table should take that much) and should hardly be measurable.

Comment: Try actually profiling your process, with (kernel) stack traces during the fork. Something on your system is behaving irregular.

Comment: @Ext3h It's 7k/s, and it lasts about 5-10 seconds, even the child process exits.